# JQuery seting input field from confirm dialogue

Tags: jquery

I want to set the input field "text_abort_input_jquery" from a JQuery dialogue. 
I have this form:

```
<form id="target_abort_input" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="text_abort_input"/>
    <input type="text" id="text_abort_input_jquery"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit_abort_input" />
</form>
```

where the user first inputs a value in the first input, which is displayed in a confirm dialogue where the user can a, press OK, b, press cancel, and c, input text which is then set in the second input field "text_abort_input_jquery".

This is my script so far:

```
$('#target_abort_input').submit(function() {
    window.confirm( $('#text_abort_input').val() );
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: Have you been through the jQuery UI Dialog examples?

Comment: i didn't understand what means by `where the user can a, press OK, b, press cancel, and c,` didn't u show ur complete code??

Comment: `confirm()` creates a standard browser dialog, not a jQuery UI dialog.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in this manner, since the confirm dialog takes precedence. The only way to allow all 3 options at once would be to create your own dialog (e.g. with jQuery UI), and put an input box in it.

Alternatively, instead of a dialog box, use standard HTML buttons.